# Warning: chmod(): Can not call chmod() for a non-standard stream in xampp

Tags: php

I am trying to change file permission to 0777 in php but I get this error:

> Warning: chmod(): Can not call chmod() for a non-standard stream in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/jayco/gallery.php on line 55 File not readable

```
$file_folder =   BASE_URL;"media/product";
chmod($file_folder.$zip_name, 0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` like this:

```
$file_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."media/product";
chmod($file_folder.$zip_name, 0777);
```

Chmod doesnot support URLs, therefore you are receiving this error.